# How to check on which OS system the python program is running to import rpi.gpio?

Tags: python, pi-4, rpi.gpio, windows

Is there an easy way to let a python program check if it running on the raspberry Pi or the pc running windows? I would like to use this to automaticly use the rpi.gpio functions in my code.

I am looking for a similair implementations as i use for debug modes:

```
if __debug__:
   import [some library]
```

I already found some examples that use os.uname(), but after testing this in python3 idle i found out that this was not working for me.

Does anybody know a good and simple way to implement this?

Comment: It is difficult to imagine any program requiring RPi.GPIO which would run on Windows. Although having said that you can access the Pi remotely using pigpio.

Comment: The project is with OpenCV and has some output via the gpio, but i am mostly testing the OpenCV part on my pc. since the pc does not have to use or can use rpi.gpio i would like to be able to run the code without commenting all rpio.gpio stuff out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `sys.platform`.

```
import sys
print(sys.platform)
```

On my Linux laptop it reports `linux2`.

Comment: Thanks @joan, that solutions works great for me!

Comment: @Rens: [Please read this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when you have a moment.

Comment: @Seamus i don't have the reputation to upvote it, but did accept the answer. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @Rens: Huh! Didn't know rep was required to upvote, but I just upvoted your Q, so that moves you in the right direction :)